# Use ggplot2 and tablegrob to plot grouped boxplots with summary statistics from multiple matrices with NA values

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

I've searched around for a while but I still can't solve this minor issue in which I would like to change the decimal place of numbers in the table created by `tablegrob()`. Doing so would make the entire view look better, **as seen below:**

[image]

**This is the code:**

```
a<-as.vector(matrixA) #matrices A-D contain randomly generated NA and 
b<-as.vector(matrixB) #numerical values
c<-as.vector(matrixC)
d<-as.vector(matrixD)
data <- cbind(a, b, c, d)
plot <- melt(data)
colnames(plot)[2]<-"variable"
plot<-plot[,-1]
levels(df$variable) <- c("A", "B", "C",
                                  "D")
xlabs <- paste(levels(plot$variable),"\n(N=",
               colSums(!is.na(data)),")",sep="")
boxplot1<-ggplot(na.omit(plot),aes(x=variable,y=value,color=variable))+
  geom_boxplot()+scale_x_discrete(labels=xlabs)+
  xlab("X") + ylab("Y")+ 
  ggtitle("Title")
#create inset table
multi.fun <- function(x) {
  c(Mean = mean(x,na.rm=TRUE), Median = median(x,na.rm=TRUE), 
    IQR = IQR(x,na.rm=TRUE))}
sum.table<-data.frame(lapply(data.frame(a,b,c,d), multi.fun))
colnames(sum.table)<- c("A", "B", "C",
                        "D")
my_table <- tableGrob(sum.table, **digits=2**, gpar.coretext = gpar(fontsize=8), 
                      gpar.coltext=gpar(fontsize=8), gpar.rowtext=gpar(fontsize=8))
#Create the viewports, push them, draw and go up
grid.newpage()
vp1 <- viewport(width = 0.75, height = 1, x = 0.375, y = .5)
subvp <- viewport(width = 0.3, height = 0.3, x = 0.75, y = 0.20)
print(boxplot1, vp = vp1)
upViewport(0)
pushViewport(subvp)
grid.draw(my_table)
```

I tried adjusting the values using **`digits`** in `tablegrob`, which didn't work. I also tried **options(digits=2)**, which also didn't work. Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: I don't think tableGrob has a digits argument. You could convert your sum.table data.frame to character with your desired formatting beforehand, as in `tableGrob(format(mtcars[1:3,4:6], digits=2))`

Comment: @baptiste Could you clarify how the dimension matrix `[1:3,4:6]` works? It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: BTW, I tried your technique to add N= to the x-axis labels, but didn't succeed (I got the same count for each of my factors).  Where did dff come from?  How did you get the sums to vary by the factors A, B, C, D?  Thanks

Comment: @lawyeR I modified my original post. Hope this helps. I'm sure this code could be done in a more elegant way, too!

Comment: Thank you.  You taught me a very useful technique.

Comment: @lawyeR No problem. Hat in kind, if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
colnames(sum.table)<- c("A", "B", "C","D")
***sum.table<-format(sum.table[1:3,1:4], digits=2)***
my_table <- tableGrob(sum.table, 
            gpar.coretext = gpar(fontsize=8), gpar.coltext=gpar(fontsize=8), 
            gpar.rowtext=gpar(fontsize=8))
```

Formatting the data.frame before using tableGrob using 
`sum.table<-format(sum.table[1:3,1:4], digits=2)`, I obtain the desired outcome:

[image]